# Show shipping rate error message if no shipping method available

Tags: magento2, magento2.4.5, magento-checkout, magento-shipping

I want to show shipping rate's error message only if all shipping method available have errors.

```
<!-- ko ifnot: rates().length > 0 --><div class="no-quotes-block"><!-- ko i18n: 'Sorry, no quotes are available for this order at this time'--><!-- /ko --></div><!-- /ko -->
```

Above logic show "no quotes message" if no rates available but will not work if there are shipping rates available but all have error message.

How to show error message if all shipping rates have error message?